# React Native - Pause Video on Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-video

In my react-native project, I'm using react-navigation 5 for navigation and react-native-video for a audio/video player.

My requirement is that when a user navigates to another scren, if the audio/video should stop playing. However, that's not happening and the audio keeps playing.

I have created two screens in a stack navigator. The Video Player is a separate component.

**Screen Code:**

```
function MainScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [audiostatus, setAudioStatus] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      console.log('Leaving Home Screen');
      setAudioStatus(true);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <Player tracks={TRACKS} paused={audiostatus} />
      <Button
        title="Go to Screen Without Audio"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('No Audio Screen')}
      />
      <Button
        title="Go to Screen With Another Audio (Love Yourself)"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Another Audio Screen')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Player Code**
Within the Player, I recieve the paused prop to decide whether the video should be already playing or paused. Then the player has controls that control the playbck by changing the state.

```
export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      paused: props.paused,
      totalLength: 1,
      currentPosition: 0,
      selectedTrack: 0,
      repeatOn: false,
      shuffleOn: false,
    };
  }


  setDuration(data) {
    this.setState({totalLength: Math.floor(data.duration)});
  }

  setTime(data) {
    this.setState({currentPosition: Math.floor(data.currentTime)});
  }

  seek(time) {
    time = Math.round(time);
    this.refs.audioElement && this.refs.audioElement.seek(time);
    this.setState({
      currentPosition: time,
      paused: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const track = this.props.tracks[this.state.selectedTrack];
    const video = this.state.isChanging ? null : (
      <Video source={{uri: track.audioUrl}} // Can be a URL or a local file.
        ref="audioElement"
        paused={this.state.paused}               // Pauses playback entirely.
        resizeMode="cover"           // Fill the whole screen at aspect ratio.
        repeat={false}                // Repeat forever.
        onLoadStart={this.loadStart} // Callback when video starts to load
        onLoad={this.setDuration.bind(this)}    // Callback when video loads
        onProgress={this.setTime.bind(this)}    // Callback every ~250ms with currentTime
        onEnd={this.onEnd}
        onError={this.videoError}
        style={styles.audioElement}
        audioOnly={true} />
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SeekBar
          onSeek={this.seek.bind(this)}
          trackLength={this.state.totalLength}
          onSlidingStart={() => this.setState({paused: true})}
          currentPosition={this.state.currentPosition} />
        <Controls
          onPressPlay={() => this.setState({paused: false})}
          onPressPause={() => this.setState({paused: true})}
          paused={this.state.paused}/>
        {video}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is that once a user starts playing the video, and then if he navigates to another screen, the video keeps playing. I want the video to pause. In the screen, i've added useEffect() to set audiostatus to pause on screen blur, but nothing happens. The video keeps playing. Please help.

Comment: Try listening for [navigation events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events) and pause when a screen blur or transition event is emitted.

Comment: I've done that. Please see the useEffect() where I'm listening to blur event in the screen. And the listener is working as the console.log prints when I go out of screen. The prop also sets to pause true (I think). But it's not taking effect in the Player.

Comment: Ah, I see that now, sorry. Looked a little deeper and see you've a duplicate "source of truth" about the paused "state". Added answer below.

Comment: I saw your answer about directly using prop instead of setting local state. I could do that. But within the player, I have some control buttons for play pause, seek, etc, And in those I change pause status with this.setState({paused: false}. I possibly can't change the prop. I wish you hadn't deleted the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that your code *did actually* update that local state, so wanted to amend my answer to work with that as consuming the `paused` prop directly would be the wrong solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following way to pause the video

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';

function MainScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [audiostatus, setAudioStatus] = useState(true);

  // create ref
  const playerRef = useRef();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      console.log('Leaving Home Screen');
      setAudioStatus(false); 

      // new code add to pause video from ref
      playerRef.current.pauseVideo();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      <Player ... playerRef={playerRef} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Convert Player class into Hooks as I did

```
import React, {useState, useImperativeHandle, useRef} from 'react';

function Player = (props) => {

  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(props.paused);
  const [totalLength, setTotalLength] = useState(1);
  const [currentPosition, setCurrentPosition] = useState(0);
  const [selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack] = useState(0);
  const [repeatOn, setRepeatOn] = useState(false);
  const [shuffleOn, setShuffleOn] = useState(false);
  const [isChanging, setIsChanging] = useState(false);

  const audioElement = useRef(null);

  const setDuration = (data) => {
    setTotalLength(Math.floor(data.duration));
  }

  const setTime = (data) => {
    setCurrentPosition(Math.floor(data.currentTime));
  }

  const seek = (time) => {
    time = Math.round(time);
    audioElement && audioElement.current.seek(time);
    setCurrentPosition(time);
    setPaused(false);
  }

  const loadStart = () => {}

  // add for accessing ref
  useImperativeHandle(props.playerRef, () => ({
    pauseVideo: () => setPaused(true),
  }));

    const track = props.tracks[selectedTrack];
    const video = isChanging ? null : (
      <Video source={{uri: track.audioUrl}} // Can be a URL or a local file.
        ref={audioElement}
        paused={paused}               // Pauses playback entirely.
        resizeMode="cover"
        ....
        onLoadStart={loadStart} // new added
        onLoad={setDuration} // new added
      />
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SeekBar
          onSeek={seek}
          trackLength={totalLength}
          onSlidingStart={() => setPaused(true)}
          currentPosition={currentPosition} />
        <Controls
          onPressPlay={() => setPaused(false) }
          onPressPause={() => setPaused(true)}
          paused={paused}/>
        {video}
      </View>
   );
}
```

Comment: I have implemented it and it's working great. Thanks. How have you utilized the setDuration function? It's not used?

Comment: actually I want to show a loading status for the time the audio loads. For that reason I had onLoadStart and onLoad in the Video component. Can I still add those?

Comment: I have implemented `onLoadStart` and `onLoad` and updated my answer so you can implement it as well

Comment: Thank you. I've awarded the bounty to you.

Comment: Just one change I made to this was to use "const Player = (props) => {" instead of "function Player = (props) => {" and then exporting it exclusively.

Comment: if I have to add two players in the same screen, then how should I use the useRef()? Should I create two instances of playerRef? as playerRef1 and playerRef2?

Comment: Yes, you would have to create two instances

Comment: Its not working anymore. I am using react-native-video 5.2.1 and it crashes saying:
pauseVideo is not a function.

Answer (score 9):

A simple solution with functional components and hooks is to use

> useIsFocused

which returns true or false and re-renders component when changed import it using

```
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';

 const screenIsFocused = useIsFocused();
```

if you're using "react-native-video" or any other library that takes something like

> isPaused

you can use

```
 paused={isPaused || (!screenIsFocused )}
```

video will only run when it is not paused and the screen is also in focus

Answer (score 0):

Your `Player` appears to only refer to the `paused` prop only once when it mounts, in the constructor. `Player` doesn't react or handle any changes to `props.paused` when it changes in the parent component and is passed after mounting. Implement `componentDidUpdate` to react to updates to `props.paused` to update the component state.

```
export default class Player extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      paused: props.paused,
      totalLength: 1,
      currentPosition: 0,
      selectedTrack: 0,
      repeatOn: false,
      shuffleOn: false,
    };
  }

  ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { paused } = this.props;
    if (!prevState.paused && paused) {
      this.setState({ paused });
    }
  }

  ...

  render() {
    ...
    const video = this.state.isChanging ? null : (
      <Video
        ...
        paused={this.state.paused}
        ...
      />
    );

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        ...
        {video}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it did not work. Also the componentDidUpdate is called continuously. I added a console.log statement to it and it keeps displaying 100s of times.

Comment: @asanas Ack, I think inverted the `paused` prop in the conditional test. What is desired is: If the current `state.paused` is false and a new `props.paused` is true, then update `state.paused` to be true.

Comment: Ok, now my video is permanently paused. Even if I click the play button, it sets back to pause. Can I contact you? Can we engage professionally?

Comment: @asanas This is common issue with duplicated state (trying to synchronize them) and it's nearly 2am for me, I can't engage now. I'll take another look in about 6 hours.

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps would probably be more appropriate than updating state in `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: @DrewReese did you get a chance to look at it? Sorry, if I'm bothering you.